# is there "force" to be online?

Tags: 12.10, boot, kernel, internet

When I boot after plugged off the internet-network-cable - then booting hangs itself up at
"configuring network" - that was not the case with Kernel 3.2 ?

I just noticed that this happens with Kernel 3.9 and with 3.10 when booting offline ?

In /etc/network/interfaces the entries look just normal - I think so ? :

> auto lo
>
> iface lo inet loopback
>
> auto eth0
>
> iface eth0 inet dhcp

Next to dhcp lines in syslog there is output of apparmor (of actually working kernel with internet-connection) ... is this then an issue about apparmor ?!

Comment: How is your network configured? DHCP or static IP? Could you show your `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: @January - have added some lines here. It is cable modem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not know this solution earlier, cause detected it accidentally later. Apparently this so-called "bug" as described above is nothing to do with kernel or with file /etc/network/interfaces ?

Everybody who had this problem like above described in question - with machine un-plugged to internet not able to boot into display-manager - can test if this problem can be solved with deleting file .ICEauthority and create it new again :

> cd /home/$user
>
> rm .ICEauthority
>
> touch .ICEauthority
>
> chmod 755 .ICEauthority

Then probably it helps to clean the installation of display-managers with reinstallation.

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall xdm
>
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm
>
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall gdm
>
> sudo reboot

(In the end re-installation of graphics-drivers is not necessary !)

Answer (score 1):

Your network configuration specifies an eth0 interface to be configured via DHCP. Thus, the startup scripts will "hang" (not really, they start the process, wait a while and then timeout, but they do stop the rest of the boot process) while the network is brought up to what you specified in this file.

If this is a desktop Ubuntu installation, you can remove the two `eth0` lines. The interface will not be managed by the startup scripts, but by NetworkManager which starts later in the boot process and will not hold things up. This means that things should still work correctly when you have the cable plugged in with NetworkManager configuring the interface via DHCP.

Comment: would then booting the system work, when I plug-off the network-cable for to work offline (before I switch on - ... (... and before I close myself out))? - you mean I should remove 'eth0' as entry ? - this is not logical to me ...

Comment: You should edit the file with a text editor and delete the two lines mentioning eth0. Leave the ones with `lo`. You can make a backup copy of the file before changing it, if things don't work, you can restore the backup to get things to how they were before.

Comment: it is sufficient (for to boot without network-cable plugged in) to delete only 'auto eth0' - but later when I want to use internet again, 'auto eth0' is needed to be added back to interfaces-file and I need to plug-in network-cable and reboot. ...at moment a bit humblesome, but can live with it, when need to be off-line.