# Why is 'auto eth0' a problem to Kernel > 3.2?

Tags: networking, kernel, ethernet

With this new question I refer to this previous question :

[is there "force" to be online?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320582/is-there-force-to-be-online)

Why is 'auto eth0' in file /etc/network/interfaces a problem to the Kernels > 3.2 ?

When entry 'auto eth0' is given, and machine is unplugged to the network-cable, then machine cannot boot further than "configuring network" and hangs itselfs up.

When I delete 'auto eth0' then machine can boot normal without being plugged to the network-cable.

This was not the case with Kernel 3.2.x

( But when I want to be back to internet - have to add back 'auto eth0' again .)

Answer (score 1):

If you declare 'auto eth0' in /etc/network/interfaces, you are telling the system to connect the ethernet automatically. But then, as you said, you have disconnected the ethernet cable. You have given the system an impossible task: to connect the ethernet but without a cable connection to the router! The system will try to follow your instructions for several minutes and will eventually boot *without* the connection you requested.

Usually, Network Manager will handle all this for you with no entries in /etc/network/interfaces except for loopback. If that is not happening, you will have better luck troubleshooting NM rather than giving the system an unresolvable problem.